# Swift if conditional: Is 'comma' like 'AND'?

Tags: swift

I'm working through the Swift tutorial and at one point, an if condition is evaluated where a comma `,` separates two conditions. Is this the same like an `AND` operator? As in:

```
var a = 3
var b = 6

var c = 9
var d = 15

if a < b &&  d > c {
    print("yes")
}

if a < b,  d > c {
    print("yes")
}
```

Both cases return `yes`.

Comment: similar, not the exactly same

Comment: I was trying to find an explanation in the guidelines but commas are discussed only in switch statements, not if clauses. Can you point me to this?

Comment: For one thing, the precedence of `&&` and `,` is different, therefore they are not the same. I am sure there is already a duplicate question but I am unable to find it right now.